# How are the digits of an irrational number computed?

Tags: irrational-numbers

I have a question about irrational or just long sequences of rational numbers.

What method/algorithm is used to determine what digit will come next in the sequence, I mean how do they know for sure? It is a random sequence after all right?

Just tell me how they find the next number in "pi". I know they do it with computers and math, but what is the theory behind knowing what number comes next.

Comment: What is a random sequence? Not all sequences are random.

Comment: For $\pi$ specifically [Machin's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MachinsFormula.html) was used to calculate 500 or so first decimals. Nowadays they use formulas that converge faster.

Comment: They can because $\pi$ is not a random sequence of digits: we know many properties of the sequence and so we are able to evaluate if a digit is correct or not. If you were to use extracts from the decimal representation of $\pi$ as key for an encryption algorithm it is pretty easy that someone would be able to recognize your algorithm and crack your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Only for a tiny fraction of irrational numbers there is an algorithm that produces the digits in their decimal expansion, because there is only a countable number of algorithms!

Nevertheless, *every* real number has a decimal expansion, which is unique except for terminating decimals like $1=0.999\cdots$.

There are [several methods for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_pi).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the example of $\pi$, there are various formulas which converge at $\pi$. I don't remember one about $\pi$ but we can define $e$ as $$\lim_{x\ \rightarrow \infty} \huge( \normalsize 1 + \frac{1}{x}\huge )\normalsize ^x$$ As you begin to take higher and higher values of $x$, you will notice that the answer begins to get nearer and nearer to $e$.

Comment: "diverge towards" ?

Answer (score 1):

One simple formula for pi is 
$$\frac\pi4=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19\cdots$$
This formula comes from calculus.  It also uses the fact that, in radians, $\tan(\pi/4)=1$.
The formulas that people actually use approach $\pi$ much more quickly than this one.

Comment: This does not actually address how to find the next digit in the sequence (at least not directly).